# Argument 'AccordionDemoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the error:

> Argument 'AccordionDemoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined.

My Javascript file is:

```
angular.module('DatePicker', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module('DatePicker').controller('DatepickerPopup', function ($scope) {
    $scope.today = function () {
        $scope.dt = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.dt = null;
    };

    $scope.inlineOptions = {
        customClass: getDayClass,
        minDate: new Date(),
        showWeeks: true
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        dateDisabled: disabled,
        formatYear: 'yy',
        maxDate: new Date(2040, 5, 22),
        minDate: new Date(),
        startingDay: 1
    };

    // Disable weekend selection
    function disabled(data) {
        var date = data.date,
          mode = data.mode;
        return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
    }

    $scope.toggleMin = function () {
        $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
        $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
    };

    $scope.toggleMin();

    //$scope.open1 = function () {
    //    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
    //};

    $scope.open2 = function () {
        $scope.popup2.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.setDate = function (year, month, day) {
        $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
    };

    //$scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
    //$scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

    $scope.popup1 = {
        opened: false
    };

    $scope.popup2 = {
        opened: false
    };

    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    var afterTomorrow = new Date();
    afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    $scope.events = [
      {
          date: tomorrow,
          status: 'full'
      },
      {
          date: afterTomorrow,
          status: 'partially'
      }
    ];

    function getDayClass(data) {
        var date = data.date,
          mode = data.mode;
        if (mode === 'day') {
            var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
                var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

                if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
                    return $scope.events[i].status;
                }
            }
        }

        return '';
    }
});
angular.module('DatePicker',[]).controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.oneAtATime = true;

    $scope.groups = [
      {
          title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
          content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1'
      },
      {
          title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
          content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2'
      }
    ];

    $scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

    $scope.addItem = function () {
        var newItemNo = $scope.items.length + 1;
        $scope.items.push('Item ' + newItemNo);
    };

    $scope.status = {
        isCustomHeaderOpen: false,
        isFirstOpen: true,
        isFirstDisabled: false
    };
});
```

And my HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="lsApp.DatePicker">
<head>
    <title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.js"></script>   
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <script src="Scripts/DatePicker.js">
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="group-template.html">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#fa39c3">
          <a href tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" uib-accordion-transclude="heading">
            <span uib-accordion-header ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">
              {{heading}}
            </span>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-collapse collapse" uib-collapse="!isOpen">
        <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: right" ng-transclude></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="status.open = !status.open">Toggle last panel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="status.isFirstDisabled = ! status.isFirstDisabled">Enable / Disable first panel</button>
  </p>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">
      Open only one at a time
    </label>
  </div>
  <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </div>
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
    </div>
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="Dynamic Body Content">
      <p>The body of the uib-accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="Custom template" template-url="group-template.html">
      Hello
    </div>
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="status.isCustomHeaderOpen" template-url="group-template.html">
      <uib-accordion-heading>
        Custom template with custom header template <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.isCustomHeaderOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.isCustomHeaderOpen}"></i>
      </uib-accordion-heading>
      World
    </div>
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-danger" heading="Delete account">
      <p>Please, to delete your account, click the button below</p>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="status.open">
      <uib-accordion-heading>
        I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
      </uib-accordion-heading>
      This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
    </div>
  </uib-accordion>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I am doing wrong? Why am I only getting errors in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets `[]` it should looks like :

```
angular.module('DatePicker').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to declare a controller with the module no need to mention the depdencies,

Change

**From:**

```
angular.module('DatePicker',[]).controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function
```

**To:**

```
angular.module('DatePicker').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function
```